# PHP xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx headers

Tags: php, ms-office

Here is my code where I am trying to send a correct header depedning on a type of a document. I figured out the headers for pdf, doc and docx but I still need to know correct header for Excel and Powerpoint files.

Any help appreciated.

```
    $document = urldecode($_GET['document']);
    $extension = end(explode('.', $document));
    $mimeType = '';
    switch ($extension) {
        case 'pdf':
            $mimeType = 'pdf';
            break;
        case 'doc':
            $mimeType = 'msword';
            break;
        case 'docx':
            $mimeType = 'msword';
            break;
        case 'xls':
            $mimeType = '';
            break;
        case 'xlsx':
            $mimeType = '';
            break;
        case 'ppt':
            $mimeType = '';
            break;
        case 'pptx':
            $mimeType = '';
            break;
    }       
    header('Content-type: application/' . $mimeType);
```

Comment: fabrik your link serves 'Error 404! The page you requested does not exist or has moved.' please remove your link from here.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**.xls**

application/vnd.ms-excel

**.xlsx**

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

**.ppt**

application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

**.pptx**

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

And one of those you have listed is wrong:

**.docx**

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Answer (score 5):

See http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp .

xls is `application/vnd.ms-excel`, ppt is `application/vnd.ms-powerpoint`.

Comment: Good list except it does not include .docx, .xlsx or .pptx.

Answer (score 3):

Since most of the types requested are Microsoft Office related, this link has all of the office mime types (the best focused source I've found so far): http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php

Answer (score 0):

You can simply echo $_FILES['input_tag_name']['type'] after upload a file to know the MIME type of that file.