# Determine excel file mime type

Tags: php, excel, mime-types

I need  determine  what is type  of uploaded file

When upload `.xlsx` file, this code:

```
 echo $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']."<br>";  
 echo mime_content_type($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
```

returns:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

As I know (from here [PHP xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318288/php-xls-xlsx-ppt-pptx-headers)), `application/vnd.ms-excel` is not `.xlsx`, but `.xls` file mime type.

So, why returns `mime_content_type()` function `application/vnd.ms-excel` for `.xlsx` file? where the truth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[mime_content_type()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) isn't particularly accurate, and has been deprecated in favour of [Fileinfo()'s mime_content_type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php); although personally, I open the file and test explicitly for certain data elements in the files that might not be included as part of the mime_magic signature details

Answer (score 12):

Use [FileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.finfo-file.php) instead of mime_content_type (which is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263957/why-is-mime-content-type-deprecated-in-php)).

Regarding mime-types and extensions,

```
application/vnd.ms-excel                                          xls xlb xlt
application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12                    xlam
application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12             xlsb
application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12                    xlsm
application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12                 xltm
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx
```

(available at /etc/mime.types in your linux webserver)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an wrapper that will properly identify Microsoft Office 2007 documents. It's trivial and straightforward to use, edit, and to add more file extentions/mimetypes.

```
function get_mimetype($filepath) {
    if(!preg_match('/\.[^\/\\\\]+$/',$filepath)) {
        return finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $filepath);
    }
    switch(strtolower(preg_replace('/^.*\./','',$filepath))) {
        // START MS Office 2007 Docs
        case 'docx':
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
        case 'docm':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'dotx':
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template';
        case 'dotm':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'xlsx':
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
        case 'xlsm':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'xltx':
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template';
        case 'xltm':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'xlsb':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'xlam':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'pptx':
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation';
        case 'pptm':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'ppsx':
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow';
        case 'ppsm':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'potx':
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template';
        case 'potm':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'ppam':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'sldx':
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide';
        case 'sldm':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12';
        case 'one':
            return 'application/msonenote';
        case 'onetoc2':
            return 'application/msonenote';
        case 'onetmp':
            return 'application/msonenote';
        case 'onepkg':
            return 'application/msonenote';
        case 'thmx':
            return 'application/vnd.ms-officetheme';
            //END MS Office 2007 Docs

    }
    return finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $filepath);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see warning on [mime_content_type](https://www.php.net/mime_content_type) function page it is **outdated** now & it got replaced by [**finfo**](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.fileinfo.php) function.

```
$finfo = new finfo(); 
$fileinfo = $finfo->file($file, FILEINFO_MIME);
```

To install `finfo` extension.

```
pecl install fileinfo
```